# Error "ld: library not found for -lGTLTouchStaticLib" when linking Google APIs Objective-C Client Library as static library to app

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, google-client

I try linking an app to the iOS Static Library for the Google APIs Objective-C Client Library as described [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary). This involved dragging libGTLTouchStaticLib.a from GTL.xcodeproj's Products area in the Xcode Project Navigator view to the app's Link Binaries With Libraries build phase.

I currently run into this error when building the app project in Xcode 5.1.1:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option  
'-L/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GTL-abc/Build/Products/Debug'
ld: library not found for -lGTLTouchStaticLib clang: error: linker
command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Further investigation reveals the following:

- Xcode reports the Full Path for the Product libGTLTouchStaticLib.a in GTL.xcodeproj as /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GTL-abc/Build/Products/Debug/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a (i.e. w/o suffix -iphoneos)
- However, (the OS X command) `ls` reports its location as /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GTL-abc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a (i.e. with suffix -iphoneos)
- Dragging libGTLTouchStaticLib.a has apparently added the following entry to the app's Library Search Path (under Build Settings): $(USER_LIBRARY_DIR)/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GTL-abc/Build/Products/Debug (i.e. w/o suffix -iphoneos)

What causes the different application of suffixes by the two Xcode projects and how can I align their behavior in the "normal" way (i.e. without "hacking" the app's Library Search Path).